# Custom Webpack CSS-loader "localIdentName" Query Tag Placeholders?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, loader

I'm brand new to Webpack and have been playing around with the css-loader. [On the Github page under "Local Scope"](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#user-content-local-scope) there's information about specifying a `localIdentName` query tag with your own custom values like: `[path][name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]`. This tag allows us to specify how the class should be named after being processed.

Is it possible for us to define our own custom value placeholders for this query tag i.e. `css-loader?localIdentName=[MyCustomMethod]-[hash:base64:5]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to put an arbitrary custom token there, but the documentation for `loader-utils` (which is used by css-loader) lists [a number of other useful predefined tokens](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#interpolatename) such as `[folder]` or `[emoji]`. Maybe they'll do?